# Why is my destructor called only once and not on the delete(a) call?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, destructor

```cpp
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B {};

class C : public A {
    public:
    C(){ b = new B();}
    B* b;
    ~C(){
        printf("in destructor\n");
        delete b;
    }
};

void doSomething(A&aref)
{
    C c = (C &) aref;
    c.b = new B();
    int i;
}

int main()
{      
    A * a;

    a = new C();
    printf("Line 1\n");
    doSomething(*a);
    printf("Line 2\n");

    delete(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Line 1
in destructor
Line 2
```

Tried removing the `delete(a)` and get same results.

Why don't I see the destructor called twice?  I'd expect it to be called at the end of the `doSomething` function and at the `delete` call.

Why does the `doSomething` function call the destructor? And why does the `delete(a)` not cause an error?

Comment: Also, you should prefer to use `std::unique_ptr` rather than raw pointers

Comment: I like the random `int i;` at end of function

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `virtual` destructor in `A`, hence the undefined behavior.
Default one for defined behavior.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;  
};
```

Comment: That's such a common mistake that I would rather introduce a complier warning of inheriting a class without corral destructor and have a special explicit tag to disable it